# Как на Delphi реализовать получение обновлений от telegram бота через webhook?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-tokyo

Для решения данной задачи пытаюсь использовать `TIdHTTPServer`. Поддержка https при помощи `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` и [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) библиотеки. Самозаверенный SSL ключ и сертификат создаю согласно [инструкции](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed). Адрес для скидывания обновлений назначил таким образом: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<..токен..>/setWebhook?url=https://46.251.XXX.XXX`

Конфиг сервера:

```
HandlerSSL:= TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(nil);
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'MYPUBLIC.pem';
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'MYPRIVATE.key';
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'MYPUBLIC.pem';
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 1;
HandlerSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];

IdHttpServer.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
IdHTTPServer.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;
IdHTTPServer.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
if AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port = 443 then
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.Socket).PassThrough := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1QuerySSLPort(APort: Word; var VUseSSL: Boolean);
begin
  VUseSSL := (APort = 443);
end;
```

Для визуализации:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  HtmlStr: String;
  i: integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.RemoteIP);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.Command);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ARequestInfo.RawHeaders.Text);

  HtmlStr :=
    '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<title>Testing</title>'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    ARequestInfo.Command+'<br>'+
    ARequestInfo.RemoteIP+'<br>';
      for i := 0 to ARequestInfo.RawHeaders.Count-1 do
        begin
          HtmlStr := Str+ ARequestInfo.RawHeaders[i]+'<br>'
        end;
    HtmlStr := Str +
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := HtmlStr;
end;
```

Сервер с внешней сети виден со всеми портами, браузеры конечно ругаются на ненадежный сертификат, но тем не менее ответ заданный в `OnCommandGet` от сервера приходит. Однако со стороны телеграма я даже не вижу попыток подсоедениться к серверу, getWebhookinfo возвращает:

```
{
    "ok":true,
    "result":
        {
        "url":"https://46.251.XXX.XXX",
        "has_custom_certificate":false,
        "pending_update_count":35,
        "last_error_date":1555526934,
        "last_error_message":"Connection timeout expired",
        "max_connections":40
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько возможных вариантов для ответа на твой вопрос:

1. Если данный IP адрес сам из России - тогда, ответ очевиден, что Роскомнадзор - блокирует IP адреса самого Telegram'а, и он просто не может отстучать по IP адресу, который ты вводишь в WebHook.
2. Советую, использовать библиотеку [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start), здесь вы так же сможете найти примеры по реализации Web-Сервера.
3. Советую взять доменное имя, и привязать его к IP адресу (и получить бесплатный сертификат от Let's Encryrpt.