# Деплой телеграм бота на VPS

Tags: java, proxy, vps

Залил telegram бота на vps, сначала была ошибка 403 с первого же запроса, купил прокси, теперь Connection timed out. В чем может быть проблема? Сервер слишком далеко? На локальном все идеально работает.

Comment: Смотри здесь мой пост, тут ты должен найти решение своей проблемы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/972810/277283 Если помог, жми палец вверх!)

Answer (score 0):

С деплоем на VPS не помогу, но могу посоветовать более простой способ деплоя собственных телеграмм ботов на Java. Есть очень хороший облачный сервис [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java)
с помощью его ты легко можешь деплоить своего бота прямо из командной строки сделав пуш в репозиторий. Также есть вариант настроить пуш прямо из GitHub. Если заинтересовала, могу помочь с первым деплоем на Heroku.

Comment: пробовал)бесплатная версия работает по 30 сек) а платная дорого) спасибо за совет)я уже разобрался)проблема была сервере, сменил сервер на KVM и все заработало

Comment: У меня мои боты все на бесплатной версии и нормально себя чувствуют, да когда нет трафика они засыпают, и потом первый запрос немного тс задержкой, но это не критично в моем случае. Отлично что разобрались и удачи в будущем)